# User input field to rename multiple files

Tags: python, tkinter, input, dynamic

I am trying to make something to rename multiple files (by user's choice)
everything is OK but I can't make it to get the user's input for rename.

in here when I run this program, I want to put in name field something like: `"newname"`
and also I want to put in date field something like: `2020`.

These `newname` and `2020` are in the code by default and program will automatically do that. I want to prevent it and make it dynamic. Code is:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Rename Helper")

hlabel = Label(window, text="Name")
hlabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

dlabel = Label(window, text="Date")
dlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

hl_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=hl_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

d_text = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=d_text)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)

fileExt = (".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".PNG", "JPG", ".JPEG")
def rename(path, new_name, numbering, d_text, extension,):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    count = numbering
    for i in list:
        if i.endswith(fileExt):
            os.rename(i, new_name + "_P_" + str(count).zfill(2) + "_" + d_text + '.' + extension)
            count += 1

path = os.path.abspath('./')

def renamebtn():
    rename(path, 'newname', 1, "2020", "jpg")

btn1 = Button(window, text="Rename", command=renamebtn)
btn1.grid(row=3, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in just about any tkinter documentation. Why do you need out help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the entry field values using the `get()` method of the linked variables:

```
def renamebtn():
    newname = hl_text.get()
    newdate = d_text.get()
    print(newname, newdate)
    #rename(path, newname, 1, newdate, "jpg")
```